# Pictures taken from front camera becomes black when uploaded

Tags: php

I'm using GD library to resize the images and exif to fix the orientation. It works just fine, but on some specific devices like Samsung Galaxies, pic taken from front camera that gets uploaded becomes black. How do I fix it?

Image Resizing method:

```
public function process($task, $savePath, $taskWidth=0, $taskHeight=0, $quality=80)
{
    $quality = (int) $quality;
    $quality = ($quality < 0 or $quality > 100) ? 80 : $quality;

    if (file_exists ($this->path))
    {
        if (in_array($this->extension, $this->photoExtensions))
        {
            if ($this->extension == "gif")
            {
                copy($this->path, $savePath);
                return true;
            }

            switch ($this->extension)
            {
                case 'png':
                    $im = imagecreatefrompng($this->path);
                    break;

                default:
                    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->path);
                    break;
            }

            if ($task == "crop")
            {
                if ($taskWidth > 0 && $taskHeight > 0)
                {
                    $cropWidth = $this->imageWidth;
                    $cropHeight = $this->imageHeight;
                    $ratioWidth = 1;
                    $ratioHeight = 1;
                    $destinationX = 0;
                    $destinationY = 0;
                    $sourceX = 0;
                    $sourceY = 0;

                    $cropWidth = ($taskWidth == 0 || $taskWidth > $this->imageWidth) ? $this->imageWidth : $taskWidth;
                    $cropHeight = ($taskHeight == 0 || $taskHeight > $this->imageHeight) ? $this->imageHeight : $taskHeight;

                    if ($cropWidth > $this->imageWidth)
                    {
                        $destinationX = ($cropWidth - $this->imageWidth) / 2;
                    }

                    if ($cropHeight > $this->imageHeight)
                    {
                        $destinationY = ($cropHeight - $this->imageHeight) / 2;
                    }

                    if ($cropWidth < $this->imageWidth || $cropHeight < $this->imageHeight)
                    {
                        $ratioWidth = $cropWidth / $this->imageWidth;
                        $ratioHeight = $cropHeight / $this->imageHeight;

                        if ($cropHeight > $this->imageHeight)
                        {
                            $sourceX  = ($this->imageWidth - $cropWidth) / 2;
                        }
                        elseif ($cropWidth > $this->imageWidth)
                        {
                            $sourceY  = ($this->imageHeight - $cropHeight) / 2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if ($ratioHeight > $ratioWidth)
                            {
                                $sourceX = round(($this->imageWidth - ($cropWidth / $ratioHeight)) / 2);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $sourceY = round(($this->imageHeight - ($cropHeight / $ratioWidth)) / 2);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $cropImage = @imagecreatetruecolor($cropWidth, $cropHeight);

                    if ($this->extension == "png")
                    {
                        @imagesavealpha($cropImage, true);
                        @imagefill($cropImage, 0, 0, @imagecolorallocatealpha($cropImage, 0, 0, 0, 127));
                    }

                    @imagecopyresampled($cropImage, $im ,$destinationX, $destinationY, $sourceX, $sourceY, $cropWidth - 2 * $destinationX, $cropHeight - 2 * $destinationY, $this->imageWidth - 2 * $sourceX, $this->imageHeight - 2 * $sourceY);

                    @imageinterlace($cropImage, true);

                    switch ($this->extension)
                    {
                        case 'png':
                            @imagepng($cropImage, $savePath);
                            break;

                        default:
                            @imagejpeg($cropImage, $savePath, $quality);
                            break;
                    }

                    @imagedestroy($cropImage);
                }
            }
            elseif ($task == "resize")
            {
                if ($taskWidth == 0 && $taskHeight == 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if ($taskWidth > 0 && $taskHeight == 0)
                {
                    $resizeWidth = $taskWidth;
                    $resizeRatio = $resizeWidth / $this->imageWidth;
                    $resizeHeight = floor($this->imageHeight * $resizeRatio);
                }
                elseif ($taskHeight > 0 && $taskWidth == 0)
                {
                    $resizeHeight = $taskHeight;
                    $resizeRatio = $resizeHeight / $this->imageHeight;
                    $resizeWidth = floor($this->imageWidth * $resizeRatio);
                }
                elseif ($taskWidth > 0 && $taskHeight > 0)
                {
                    $resizeWidth = $taskWidth;
                    $resizeHeight = $taskHeight;
                }

                $resizeImage = @imagecreatetruecolor($resizeWidth, $resizeHeight);

                if ($this->extension == "png")
                {
                    @imagesavealpha($resizeImage, true);
                    @imagefill($resizeImage, 0, 0, @imagecolorallocatealpha($resizeImage, 0, 0, 0, 127));
                }

                @imagecopyresampled($resizeImage, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $resizeWidth, $resizeHeight, $this->imageWidth, $this->imageHeight);
                @imageinterlace($resizeImage, true);

                switch ($this->extension)
                {
                    case 'png':
                        @imagepng($resizeImage, $savePath);
                        break;

                    default:
                        @imagejpeg($resizeImage, $savePath, $quality);
                        break;
                }

                @imagedestroy($resizeImage);
            }
            elseif ($task == "scale")
            {
                if ($taskWidth == 0)
                {
                    $taskWidth = 100;
                }

                if ($taskHeight == 0)
                {
                    $taskHeight = 100;
                }

                $scaleWidth = $this->imageWidth * ($taskWidth / 100);
                $scaleHeight = $this->imageHeight * ($taskHeight / 100);
                $scaleImage = @imagecreatetruecolor($scaleWidth, $scaleHeight);

                if ($this->extension == "png")
                {
                    @imagesavealpha($scaleImage, true);
                    @imagefill($scaleImage, 0, 0, imagecolorallocatealpha($scaleImage, 0, 0, 0, 127));
                }

                @imagecopyresampled($scaleImage, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $scaleWidth, $scaleHeight, $this->imageWidth, $this->imageHeight);
                @imageinterlace($scaleImage, true);

                switch ($this->extension)
                {
                    case 'png':
                        @imagepng($scaleImage, $savePath);
                        break;

                    default:
                        @imagejpeg($scaleImage, $savePath, $quality);
                        break;
                }

                @imagedestroy($scaleImage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using imagick? it's way better than gd

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: @flex_ Do I need to install it on the server or is it like a library to download from Git?

Comment: I can but is it relevant? Upload works for all devices except Samsung Galaxies front camera.

Comment: When you ask a question, please provide the code. Without it, the answers will be primarily opinion based.

Comment: Okay, I added the method that I use for image manipulation.

Comment: @TrondroMulligan Can you show the upload and the contents of $this->photoExtensions

Had you checked the file extension saved matches what it should be ?
Ie. it's not a jpeg but being saved as a .png

Comment: @chip Yes, I have. If the issue was this obvious, it wouldn't be working at all. But it works, just not on Samsung devices front camera.

Comment: @TrondroMulligan it's an extension so you would have to enable it in php.ini by removing the semicolon after that you just get the dll (assuming you have windows) and put it in the ext file and it should work